# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn') when using ztree-for-vue package

Tags: jquery, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to use a tree package on my Vue+Ts website.

The package im trying to use is [zTree-for-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ztree-for-vue) that is made from jquery.

I cant seem to make it appear on my code.

Theres no error on my vs code but theres an error on the compiler

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at VueComponent.create (vue-ztree.vue?61bd:116:1)
    at VueComponent.mounted (vue-ztree.vue?61bd:169:1)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863:1)
    at callHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4235:1)
    at Object.insert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3158:1)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6390:1)
    at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6609:1)
    at Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3960:1)
    at Vue.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4081:1)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4495:1)
```

Step when i install the package.

1. I installed jquery package via npm.
2. I install ztree package via npm.
3. I installed ztree-for-vue via npm.
4. I followed the tutorial on how to use the code

Below is how Implement the code:

```
<div class="ztree">
   <vue-ztree
      :treeNodes="treeNodes"
      @onClick="handleTreeClick"
      :check="check"
      @onCheck="handleCheck"
   />
</div>

import VueZtree from "ztree-for-vue";

nodes = [
  {
    name: "父节点1",
    id: 0,
    children: [
      { name: "子节点1", id: 1 },
      {
        name: "子节点2",
        id: 2,
        children: [{ name: "子节点3", id: 3 }],
      },
    ],
  },
];
  treeNodes = this.nodes;
  check = {
    enable: true,
  };

  handleTreeClick(event, treeId, treeNode) {
    console.log(event, treeId, treeNode);
  }
  handleCheck(event, treeId, treeNode) {
    console.log(event, treeId, treeNode);
  }
```

The error is not from my code but from the package itself whereby Ts cannot properteis of undefined(reading 'fn')

In the package theres a set of code that use 'fn':

```
        create() {
            if(this.treeNodes && this.treeNodes.length) {
                this.ztree = $.fn.zTree.init($(this.getZtreeDom()),this.getTreeSettings(),this.treeNodes)
                if(typeof this.treeName == 'string') {
                    window.ztree[this.treeName] = this.ztree; 
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can you show us how you implemented the package and how are you using it?

Comment: @Esszed ive editted the question and include on how i use the package and also which line of code the 'fn' came from

Comment: Have you added jquery into your project?

Comment: Ive added it to the project. Also i tried to tweak the package and change some of the line it did make the error solved but now theres a new error of ` Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')" `